# Установить свойство transition на все элементы

Tags: css, html5

Как установить свойство CSS transition на все элементы страницы?

Comment: `* { transition: ...; }` ...

Comment: спасибо, заработало, когда вставил * { transition: ... !important; }

Comment: без !important - не работает?

Comment: Да, не работает.